# How to patch and suffle images in minibatch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I would like to load a bach of cifar-10 dataset and with the help of patchify, patch them into 3x3 smaller images, then shuffle them randomly and reasmble the images. Then plot. But the foor loop never ends. Why?

How to patch, shuffle, unpatch?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from patchify import patchify, unpatchify
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import shuffle
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms



transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])




batch_size = 4

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')



patch_size = 16  # Size of the smaller patches
stride = 16     # Stride value for patching

patched_images = []
for images, labels in trainloader:
  for i in images:
    # Convert to numpy arrays
    img = i.permute(1,2,0).numpy()

    # Patchify each image
    patched_image = patchify(img, (patch_size, patch_size, 3), stride)
    # patched_images.append(patched_image)

# # Concatenate all the patched images
# patched_images = np.concatenate(patched_images, axis=0)
```

Comment: Have you tried decorating the for loop with a progressbar to see its pace (tqdm is good for that)

Comment: I am not familiar with PyTorch API but I think iterating over a trainloader is always infinite, so would you make sure if you need to change the for loop or how you create the trainloader (maybe you define a maximum steps or iterations)